# Fourier-Legendre series - Need answers for all 5 question marks

Tags: fourier-series, absolute-value, legendre-polynomials

Let $f(x)= |x|$  on $-1\leq x\leq 1$.

Then there is a Fourier-Legendre expansion

$f(x)$ = $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_mP_m(x)$ where

$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[(x^2-1)^n\right]$

$c_0 = ?$

$c_1 = ?$

and for all $m \geq 2$

$c_m = \frac {1}{m!} \ * ? * \frac {d^k}{dx^k} \textstyle\ (x^2 - 1)$ evaluated at $x = ?$

where

$k = ?$

Comment: Although you did not say, I presume $P_n$ is the Legendre polynomial of degree n.  Is that correct?   How is the Legendre polynomial defined?

Comment: Hey, yes it is the Legendre polynomial.
It is defined as updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\on{f}\pars{x}}$ is an *even function* of $\ds{x}$. Its expansion, in terms of *Legendre Polynomials*, is given by
$\ds{\on{f}\pars{x} =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
a_{\ell}\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^{1}\on{f}\pars{x}
\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{\ell\,' = 0}^{\infty}
a_{\ell\,'}\int_{-1}^{1}
\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}
\on{P}_{2\ell\,'\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &
2\int_{0}^{1}x\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
\sum_{\ell\,' = 0}^{\infty}a_{\ell\,'}\
{2\,\delta_{2\ell,\,2\ell\,'} \over 2\pars{2\ell} + 1}
\\[5mm]
& a_{\ell}  =
\pars{4\ell + 1}
\int_{0}^{1}x\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\end{align}
In addition,
\begin{align}
{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}} & =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\on{P}_{\ell}\pars{x}h^{\ell}
\\
{1 \over \root{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}} & =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\on{P}_{\ell}\pars{x}
\,\pars{-1}^{\ell}\,h^{\ell}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}} +
{1 \over \root{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\on{P}_{2\ell}\pars{x}h^{2\ell}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
a_{\ell} & =
\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}
\\[2mm] & \bracks{h^{2\ell}}\left(%
\int_{0}^{1}{x \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}\,\dd x
\right.
\\[2mm] & \phantom{\bracks{h^{2\ell}}\,\,\,\,\,}
\left.+\int_{0}^{1}
{x \over \root{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}}\,\dd x\right)
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}\bracks{h^{2\ell}}
{\pars{1 + h^{2}}^{3/2} - 1 \over h^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}
\bracks{h^{2\ell}}
\sum_{\ell\,' = 1}^{\infty}
{3/2 \choose \ell\,'}h^{2\ell\,' - 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}
\bracks{h^{2\ell}}
\sum_{\ell\,' = 0}^{\infty}
{3/2 \choose \ell\,' + 1}h^{2\ell\,'}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}
{3/2 \choose \ell + 1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\verts{x} & =
\bbx{{2 \over 3}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{2\ell + {1 \over 2}}
{3/2 \choose \ell + 1}\on{P}_{2\ell\,}\pars{x}}
\\[2mm] &\ x \in \pars{-1,1}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't need the expansion of |x| rather the expansion of c_m